# Эффективная смена текстуры блока в зависимости от наличия соседних блоков

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть скрипт на блоках, который в зависимости от положения и расположения рядом стоящих блоков меняет текстуру на нужную, когда ломался или ставился блок рядом, чтобы было плавная картинка в целом. Также есть объект мир со скриптом игровой логики, в котором содержатся все блоки в мире. Вопрос в следующем: лучше оставить как есть, то есть каждый блок сам отслеживает положения рядом стоящих блоков, или лучше в игровой логике проходить циклом по каждому блоку и проверять это положение для каждого? как лучше будет со стороны быстродействия или работоспособности

Comment: я в юнити ноль, но просто вопрос. Вот у вас будет 2 блока, в варианте (1) получается блок 1 проверит расстояние до блока 2, а потом блок 2 проверит расстояние до блока 1? А в варианте (2) какая то логка проверит оба блока только один раз?

Comment: Ну или, например, вы заранее знаете расположение блоков, то есть вы знаете, какие блоки точно не рядом друг с другом, то есть в варианте (2) вы можете составить список соседних блоков и проверять только из один раз, когда в варианте (1) вы все ещё будете каждый блок сравнивать с каждым, даже если они не соседи и вообще в разных концах карты?

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Comment: У каждого блока есть функция, которая смотрит, есть ли вокруг него еще блоки, и положения записывает. И в зависимости от того, где есть блоки, меняется текстура

Comment: В принципе я понял к чему вы клонине, просто надо будет подумать, как это правильно сделать конкретно с моим кодом. А так понял что лучше 2 вариант

Answer (score 2):

Именование для 2д поле:

- 'Блок' называют `Tile` (плитка) или `Cell` (ячейка)
- 'Мир' называют `TileGrid`/`TileMap`/`TileBoard`.

У тайла должно быть событие изменения, на которое реагируют соседние блоки.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Tile : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum TileSide { Right, Left, Top, Down }

    public event Action Changed; // событие

    private Tile _right, _left, _top, _down;

    public void DoSomething ()
    {
        // изменения
        Changed?.Invoke(); // вызов события изменения
    }

    public void AddNeighbour (Tile tile, TileSide side)
    {
        switch (side) {
            case TileSide.Right:
                _right = tile;
                _right.Changed += OnNeighbourChange; // подписка на событие соседа
                break;
            case TileSide.Left:
                _left = tile;
                _left.Changed += OnNeighbourChange; // подписка на событие соседа
                break;
            case TileSide.Top:
                _top = tile;
                _top.Changed += OnNeighbourChange; // подписка на событие соседа
                break;
            case TileSide.Down:
                _down = tile;
                _down.Changed += OnNeighbourChange; // подписка на событие соседа
                break;
        }
    }

    private void OnNeighbourChange () // у одного из соседей изменения
    {
        
    }
}
```

---

```
public class TileGrid : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Vector2Int _gridSize = new Vector2Int(10, 10);
    [SerializeField] private Vector2 _tileSize = new Vector2(32, 32);
    [Space]
    [SerializeField] private Tile _tileTemplate;
    private Tile[,] _grid;

    private void Start ()
    {
        _grid = new Tile[_gridSize.x, _gridSize.y];
        for (int x = 0; x < _gridSize.x; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < _gridSize.y; y++)
            {
                _grid[x, y] = Instantiate(_tileTemplate, transform);
                _grid[x, y].transform.localPosition = new Vector3(x*_tileSize.x, y*_tileSize.y, 0);
            }
        for (int x = 0; x < _gridSize.x-1; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < _gridSize.y-1; y++)
            {
                SetHorizontalTilePire(_grid[x, y], _grid[x+1, y]);
                SetVerticalTilePire(_grid[x, y], _grid[x, y+1]);
            }
    }

    private void SetHorizontalTilePire (Tile left, Tile right)
    {
        left.SetNeighbour(right, Tile.TileSide.Right);
        right.SetNeighbour(left, Tile.TileSide.Left);
    }

    private void SetVerticalTilePire (Tile down, Tile top)
    {
        down.AddNeighbour(top, Tile.TileSide.Top);
        top.AddNeighbour(down, Tile.TileSide.Down);
    }
}
```